# Find all natural number $n$ for which $3^9+3^{12}+3^{15}+3^n$ is a perfect cube.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, perfect-powers

> Find all natural number $n$ for which $3^9+3^{12}+3^{15}+3^n$ is a perfect cube.

What I have tried.

$3^9+3^{12}+3^{15}+3^n$

$=3^9(757+3^{n-9})$

Let $757+3^{n-9}=a^3$

Taking modulo $3$:

$a^3\equiv 1 \pmod 3$

$\implies a\equiv 1 \pmod 3$

Also, $a^3>757>729=9^3$

$\therefore a =10+3k$

$a=10$ gives $n=14$

Now, how can I know if there is any other $n>14$ satisfying the given condition.

PS: Please not use computer programmes to answer. I want pure mathematical solution.

Comment: How do you get 757? Are the powers in initial expression correctly written?

Comment: Use \$3^{15}\$ for $3^{15}$ and \$1 \pmod 3\$ for $1 \pmod 3$. Also, here is the [MathJax reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For another solution , $n$ would have to be larger than $10^5$, hence there should be no more solutions.

Comment: Why $n$ would have to be larger than $10^5$.

Comment: @DivyaPrakashSinha Because I checked $n\le 10^5$ with PARI/GP

Comment: Please give me a mathematical proof.

Comment: In the solution, you are assuming $n>9$.

Comment: I have proved $a>9$

Comment: Where, Divya? I don't see it.

Comment: See the third last step.

Comment: Can't this question be solved without using computer?

Comment: When you write $757+3^{n-9}=a^3$ and then $a^3\equiv1\bmod3$ you are assuming $3^{n-9}$ is an integer and a multiple of $3$, so you are assuming $n>9$.

Comment: Note that $1000-757=243=3^5$. We can somehow use this by substituting $a$ by $10+3k$, cubing it and then subtracting the constants .

Comment: Now posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/340131/find-all-natural-number-n-for-which-393123153n-is-a-perfect-cube without notifying either site of the other posting.

Comment: As Gerry Myerson pointed out, it is reasonable to follow [the recommendations explained on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) when [meta-tag:cross-posting]. {There is also a post with some guidelines about cross-posting [on MathOverflow Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se/2638#2638).)
Although it seems that the MO copy might get closed https://mathoverflow.net/review/close/120015 - so in this particular case it probably does not matter that much.

Comment: May be you don't see that way, but an algorithm for listing solutions of a Thue equation (or listing integral points of an elliptic curve) is relatively deep math. Now, it may be that those instances could be solved by some other means (there are elliptic curves that can be handled with high school/second year college techniques), but that is far from certain. Unless this is from a high-school level olympiad there is no reason to suspect that such techniques would apply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check manually if there exist any solution with $n \le 9$.

Now assume $n>9$, and look at the equation $3^m+757=a^3$ modulo 7 (with $m=n-9$):

$3^m+1 \equiv 3^m+757 \equiv a^3 \equiv \{0,-1,1\} \pmod 7$

$3^m \equiv \{0,-1,-2\} \pmod 7$

$n \equiv \{3,5\} \pmod 6$

If $m=6k+3$,

$ 757 = a^3-(3^{2k+1})^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

where $b=3^{2k+1}$. Factoring 757, you can check there is no solutions.

Else, if $m=6k+5$,

$757 = a^3-3^5(3^{2k})^3 = a^3-3^5b^3$

where $b=3^{2k}$. This is a [Thue equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation), effectively solvable:

using PARI/GP

> tnf = thueinit(x^3-243)
>
> thue(tnf, 757)
>
> [[10, 1]]

you can check the only solution is $(a,b)=(10,1)$, hence $(a,n)=(10,14)$

Comment: Adding a link. Likely I am not the only reader who had not heard of Thue equations. +1, of course.

Comment: For the manual check note that $n\le9$ would have to be a multiple of $3$, else the expression has a wrong number vhf of powers of $3$ in its factorization.

Answer (score 3):

> Not a full solution, I am simply reducing the problem to that of listing integer points on two elliptic curves. IIRC this is implemented in some dedicated CAS, and therefore this gives us a route to a definite answer.

With small values of $n$ checked by brute force, we can cancel the factor $3^9$. We are thus left with the equation
$$
1+3^3+3^6+3^{n-9}=x^3\Longleftrightarrow 757+3^{n-9}=x^3.\qquad(*)
$$
Depending on the residue class of $n$ modulo three we can write $3^{n-9}=3^\epsilon y^3$ with $\epsilon\in\{0,1,2\}$.
This means that any integer solution of $(*)$ will give rise to an integer
solution of one of the following Diophantine equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^3&=y^3+757,\\
x^3&=3y^3+757,\\
x^3&=9y^3+757.
\end{aligned}
$$
Each of these defines an elliptic curve. Those are known to have only finitely many integer points $(x,y)$, and (IIRC) algorithms for finding them exist (and are available in CAS's heavily used by number theorists).

> Given such finite lists, we can quickly check whether $y$ can be a power of three in any of them.

Further remarks:

- The first elliptic curve won't produce solutions. We have
  $$y^3<y^3+757<(y+1)^3$$ whenever $y>16$, and it is easy to check that the powers of three in this range won't give us any solutions.
- Peter did an extensive computer verification for a largish range of values of $n$ (see the comments under main). So even an upper bound on the integer points (don't remember whether useful ones are known) will help us settle the main question

Comment: This is mostly an oversized comment. Unlikely to satisfy the asker, or many readers of this question, including yours truly, even if it leads to an answer.

Comment: Why $\epsilon\in\{0,1,2\}$?

Comment: @DivyaPrakashSinha If $n-9=3k+\epsilon$ then $3^{n-9}=3^\epsilon\cdot(3^k)^3$. In other words, $y=3^k$.

Answer (score -1):

Only long comment.

Let $n-9=x$, then we have equation $757+3^x=a^3$ for positive integers $a,x$.

$2\mid a$ and $a\equiv 1\pmod3$, then some prime $2<p\mid a$ and $p\equiv 2\pmod3$.

Find suitable primes $p$ and related $x$ using descrete logarithm, multiplicative order and CRT in **pari/gp**.

First, $x$ is odd, becose $8\mid a^3$, $ord_8(3)=2$ and $zlog_{3_{8}}(-757)=1$:

```
? m=Mod(3,8);
?
? h=znorder(m)
%1 = 2
?
? znlog(-757,m,h)
%2 = 1
```

gp-code for finding $p$ and $x$:

```
 forprime(p=5,100, if(p%3==2,
  m=Mod(3,p);
  h=znorder(m);
  z=znlog(-757,m,h);
  if(z,
   c=iferr(chinese(Mod(1,2),Mod(z,h)), E, 0);
   if(c,
    m=Mod(3,p^2);
    h=znorder(m);
    z=znlog(-757,m,h);
    if(z,
     c=chinese(c,Mod(z,h));
     m=Mod(3,p^3);
     h=znorder(m);
     z=znlog(-757,m,h);
     if(z,
      c=chinese(c,Mod(z,h));
      j=c.mod; c=lift(c);
      print("p = "p"    x = "c" + k*"j);
     )
    )
   )
  )
 ))
```

Output:

```
p = 5    x = 5 + k*100
p = 23    x = 8169 + k*11638
p = 29    x = 11719 + k*23548
p = 47    x = 28121 + k*101614
p = 71    x = 332919 + k*352870
```

I.e. if $23\mid a$, then $x=8169 + k\cdot 11638$, where $k$ is `0,1,2,...`.